# Making a button display a text field on click in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, actionscript

I am trying to make a button in ActionScript 3.0 that, when clicked, displays a text field that contains three paragraphs of text.

- I have a dynamic text field named `textField`.
- I have a button on stage named `learn_button`.

  ```
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;
  import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
  import flash.text.TextField;

  learn_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);

  function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
  {
      var button:DisplayObjectContainer = DisplayObjectContainer(e.target);
  var textField:TextField = TextField(learn_button.getChildByName("textField"));
  textField.text = "Three paragraphs of text...";
  }
  ```

Comment: What error do you get - or what output do you get?

Comment: 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method getChildByName through a reference with static type flash.display:SimpleButton.

Comment: is your `TextField` added to stage?

Comment: @Antizam please vote to take this question off hold. You understood what I was asking and your answer is very close. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
learn_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onButtonClick);
textField.visible=false;
function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    textField.visible=true;
    textField.text = "Three paragraphs of text...";
}
```

Comment: @Atizam: This works, but it only shows my first line of text. I actually have three paragraphs that I want to fill that text field.

Comment: Look in the textfield's settings and see if it has line wrapping. By default I think it just tries to write everything in one line, but you can turn on text wrapping and this might fix it. Otherwise try increasing the size of the textfield.

Comment: Maybe textField is not set to multiline  in properties panel

Comment: Thank you. I will try that after work tonight.